# C program Dice game output not expected

Tags: c

I am trying to create a dicegame using two c files and a header file however I believe I have an issue with main when trying to execute it as the output doesnt  come out right so I put the other functions in case however they work as intended though I might be accidently calling it in main yeilding the incorrect output

Dicegame.c File

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dicegame.h"


// Generates a psuedo random number with parameters of max and min
int getRandomNumber(int min, int max)
{  
    //  random number of determined max and min
    int rndmNum = (rand() % (max-min+1)) + min;
    return rndmNum;
}
// Will determine the type of Round that will take place
enum ROUNDTYPE getRoundType()
{  
    // declaring roundtype
    enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype;
    // random number of 1-10
    int max = 10;
    int min = 1;


    int rT = (getRandomNumber(1, 10));
    // conditionals for roundtype


    if (rT <= 2)
    {  
        // Bonus: replace “points” to be equal to 200 as calculated above using a random number generator.
        roundtype = Bonus;
        printf("\nType    : Bonus");
    }
    else if (rT >= 5)
    {  
        // Regular: keep the “points” equal to the number of points as calculated above using a random number generator.
        roundtype = Regular;
        printf("\nType    : Regular");
    }
    else
    {  
        // Double: update “points” to be equal to DOUBLE the number of points
        roundtype = Double;
        printf("\nType    : Double");
    }
    return roundtype;
}


int getRoundPoints(enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype)
{  
    // points variable
    int points;
    // conditionals to calculate points by roundtype
    if (roundtype == Bonus)
    {
        points = 200;
    }
    // print out points (20 - 200) in multiples of 20
    else if (Double == roundtype)
    {  
        points = getRandomNumber(1, 10) * 20;    
    }
    else
    {
        // print out points (10 - 100) in multiples of 10
        points = getRandomNumber(1, 10) * 10;
    }
    //printf("%d", points);
    return points; // add to return points
}


void printPlayerPoints( int p1, int p2)
{  
    printf("%d\n",p1);
    printf("%d\n\n",p2);
}


void printRoundInfo(enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype, int dice, int points)
{  
    printf("%d\n",roundtype);
    printf("Dice    : %d\n",dice);
    printf("Points  : %d\n",points);
}`
```

dicegame.h

```
#ifndef DICEGAME_H
#define DICEGAME_H

enum ROUNDTYPE{ Bonus, Double, Regular};

int getRandomNumber(int min, int max);
enum ROUNDTYPE getRoundType();
int getRoundPoints(enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype);
void printPlayerPoints( int p1, int p2);
void printRoundInfo(enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype, int dice, int points); 

#endif // DICEGAME
```

main.c

```
// Add all the includes for the required header files
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "dicegame.h"
// Start the main() function with both the parameters

int main()
{
    // Initialize the srand() to start the random generator
    srand(time(0));
    // Initialize the player-1 and player-2 points to 0
    int p1 = 0;
    int p2 = 0;
    // Initialize all other required variables
    enum ROUNDTYPE roundtype;
    int pTurn = getRandomNumber(1, 2); 
    int round = 0;  // round++ and the end of each round in loop
    int totalRnd;   
    int dice = ((rand() % 6)+1);// getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    int points;//getRoundPoints(roundtype);


    // Ask the user for the number of rounds to run the game
    printf("How many rounds would you like to play:\t");
    scanf("%d\n", &totalRnd);
    // Call printPlayerPoints() function to print the initial player points which will be 0
    printPlayerPoints(p1, p2);
    // Set up the loop to go through all the rounds one at a time
    for (int i = 0; i == totalRnd; i++ && round++)
    {
        // Call the corresponding functions to get the information for this round - gamemode, dice, points
        getRoundType();
        getRandomNumber(1, 6);
        getRoundPoints(roundtype);
        // Print round number
        printf("Round %d of %d\n", round, totalRnd);
        printf("----------------\n");
        // Print current player
        if (pTurn % 2 == 1)
        // MAIN GAME LOGIC
        // Write code here to get the main game logic using branches
        {
            //player 1 Turn
            printf("Player      : 1");
            // Success: Player-1 (odd player) is the current player and the dice rolled is odd 
            if (dice % 2 == 1)
            {
                p1 = (points += getRoundPoints(roundtype));
            }
            // Failure: Player-1 (odd player) is the current player and the dice rolled is even
            else if(dice % 2 == 0)
            {
                p1 = (points -= getRoundPoints(roundtype));
                pTurn++;
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            //player 2 Turn
            printf("Player      : 2");
            // Success: Player-2 (even player) is the current player and the dice rolled is even.
            if (dice % 2 == 0)
            {
                p2 = (points += getRoundPoints(roundtype));
            }
        // Failure: Player-2 (even player) is the current player and the dice rolled is odd.
            else if(dice % 2 == 1)
            {
                p2 = (points -= getRoundPoints(roundtype));
                pTurn++;
            }
        }
        // Call printRoundInfo() to print the round information
        printRoundInfo(roundtype, dice, points);
        // Current player gains the points, based on the type of the round (see above). The current playerÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s turn continues in the next round. ()
        // Current player incurs penalty of the same number of points, based on the type of the round (see above). In the next round, the current player is changed to the other player.
        // Call printPlayerPoints() to print the player information at the end of the round
        printPlayerPoints(p1, p2);
    }
    printf("\nGAME OVER!!\n");
    // Compare the final points for player-1 and player-2
    printf("Player 1 had: %d points\n", p1);
    printf("Player 1 had: %d points\n", p2);
    // Print the winner as the one with higher points
    if (p1 > p2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 wins!!!!\n");
    }
    else if(p2 > p1)
    {
        printf("Player 2 wins!!!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("It's a tie!!!!\n");
    }
    // Return from the main() function to end the program successfully
    return 0;
}
```

(My output)

```
Type    : RegularHow many rounds would you like to play:5
5
0
0


GAME OVER!!
Player 1 had: 0 points
Player 1 had: 0 points
It's a tie!!!!
```

I dont know how to make it properly function

(Desired output)

```
Enter the number of rounds: 5
P1      : 0
P2      : 0

ROUND 1
--------
Player  : 1
Type    : REGULAR
Dice    : 5
Points  : 70
P1      : 70
P2      : 0

ROUND 2
--------
Player  : 1
Type    : REGULAR
Dice    : 2
Points  : 50
P1      : 20
P2      : 0

ROUND 3
--------
Player  : 2
Type    : DOUBLE
Dice    : 4
Points  : 180
P1      : 20
P2      : 180

GAME OVER!!
P2 Won
```

Comment: `i++ && round++` doesn't increment `round` on the first iteration. Use `i++, round++` if you want to increment both variables every time.

Comment: I don't see how `Type : Regular` can be printing before `How many rounds would you like to play`? The first message comes from calling `getRoundType()` which is after you ask for the number of rounds.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your input on the for loop for incrementing round and as for the second comment it was due to my `getRoundType()` function having a print condition in the if statements so whenever I called it, it would print

Comment: The code has a few warnings about variables that aren't initialized. Those need to be fixed. If you are compiling with gcc or clang, be sure to use options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` to avoid such problems.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue likely lies with your for loop in `main`.

```
for (int i = 0; i == totalRnd; i++ && round++)
```

With you example input, `totalRnd` is `5`. This loop only executes while `i` is equal to `totalRnd`, which never happens. The loop never executes. This was likely meant to be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalRnd; i++ && round++)
```

Even if you enter `0` as your input for `totalRnd` the behavior is incorrect as the loop will execute once rather than zero times.

You also want to use a comma in your update rather than `&&`. The `&&` *boolean* operator only evaluates the second expression if the first is true. When `i` is `0`, `i++` returns `0`, which is false in C. Thus on the first iteration, `round` is never incremented.

By using a comma, both expressions are evaluated on all iterations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalRnd; i++, round++)
```

Comment: The loop could be simplified to `for (int round = 0; round < totalRnd; round++)` because `i` isn't used anywhere, and `round` isn't modified in the body of the loop.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks alot I made the change and it is working well